# Countif is not working across worksheet

Tags: vba

I'm trying to use VBA to define a variable off of the number of occurances happening in a single column on a different worksheet.  I'm trying to count the number of times "Underwriting" appears in column S.

I'm getting a Run-time error '438' - object doesn't support this property or method.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The error points me to the line beginning with "piperow = ...

```
Sub Resize_Template()

Dim pipeRow As Long

pipeRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pipeline - Underwriting Data D").countif(Range("S:S"), "Underwriting")

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `CountIf` is not a method of a `Worksheet` - it is an `Application.WorksheetFunction` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.`

```
pipeRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Pipeline - Underwriting Data D").Range("S:S"), "Underwriting")
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so much.